# It does not work 'actionExpresion' in dynamic menu. PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

My code is like:

```
<h:form>

<p:accordionPanel>
    <p:tab title="TAB 1">
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
        <p:menu model="#{usuarioSesion.miMenu}" />
    </h:panelGrid>
    </p:tab>
    <p:tab title="TAB 2">
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
            Ayuda
    </h:panelGrid>
    </p:tab>            
</p:accordionPanel>

</h:form>
```

My managed bean is like:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "usuarioSesion")
@SessionScoped
public class UsuarioCtrl implements Serializable{

    private DefaultMenuModel miMenu;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @PostConstruct
    private void init(){
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        Application application = facesContext.getApplication();
        ExpressionFactory expressionFactory = application.getExpressionFactory();
        ELContext elContext = facesContext.getELContext();

        miMenu = new DefaultMenuModel();
        Submenu submenu;
        submenu = new Submenu();
        submenu.setId("idCabecera");
        submenu.setLabel("Operaciones");

        MenuItem item = new MenuItem();
        item.setValue("Organismos");
        item.setId("idOrganismo");
        item.setActionExpression(expressionFactory.createMethodExpression(elContext, "#{usuarioSesion.listar2}", String.class, new Class[0]));
        item.setAjax(false);
        item.setAsync(false);
        submenu.getChildren().add(item);

        MenuItem item2 = new MenuItem();
        item2.setId("idAplicacion");
        item2.setValue("Aplicacion");
        item2.setActionExpression(expressionFactory.createMethodExpression(elContext, "#{usuarioSesion.listar1}", String.class, new Class[0]));
        item2.setAjax(false);
        item2.setAsync(false);
        submenu.getChildren().add(item2);

        miMenu.addSubmenu(submenu);

    }

    public String listar1(){
        .....
    }

    public String listar2(){
        .....
    }
```

When running this code when I click on the menu item, the method listar1(), listar2() is never executed.

What is the reason?

HOWEVER with this code:

```
<h:form>
      <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
         <p:menu model="#{usuarioSesion.miMenu}" />
   </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

The menu works fine. Why???

thanks

Comment: Please add your PF and JSF versions.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: I found that adding:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10" style="display:none">
    <p:menu model="#{usuarioSesion.miMenu}" />
</h:panelGrid>
```

to your form, resolve the problem. The final form content would be:

```
<h:form>
<p:accordionPanel>
    <p:tab title="TAB 1">
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
        <p:menu model="#{usuarioSesion.miMenu}" />
    </h:panelGrid>
    </p:tab>
    <p:tab title="TAB 2">
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
            Ayuda
    </h:panelGrid>
    </p:tab>            
</p:accordionPanel>
<h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10" style="display:none">
    <p:menu model="#{usuarioSesion.miMenu}" />
</h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```